# Авторизация и привязка HWID winforms C# PHP

Tags: php, c#, winforms

хочу сделать привязку приложения по HWID для этого использовала xNet: https://github.com/X-rus/xNet/releases

Но не чего не вышло прошу посмотреть код может кто увидит проблему, я очень плохо понимаю php может там и есть косяк.

PHP
фаил globals:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_LOGIN", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_NAME", "mysoft_db");
```

фаил index:

```
include  'globals.php';

if($_POST['login'] == null || $_POST['password']  == null || $_POST['hwid'] == null)
    die();

$controller = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$u_login = $_POST['login'];
$u_password = $_POST['password'];
$u_hwid = $_POST['hwid'];

$rsp = $controller->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$u_login' AND password='$u_password'");
if($rsp->num_rows == 0)
    die("2");


$u_data = $rsp->fetch_assoc();

$id = $u_data['id'];
$db_hwid = $u_data['hwid'];

if($db_hwid == null){
    $controller->query("UPDATE users SET hwid='$u_hwid' WHERE id='$id'");
    die("3");

}

if($db_hwid != $u_hwid){
    die("4");
}
```

Класс GetData:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Management;

namespace kicklag
{
    class GetData

    {
        public static string GetMd5(string data)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

            MD5CryptoServiceProvider csp = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] byteHash = csp.ComputeHash(bytes);

            string hash = "";

            foreach (byte b in byteHash)
                  hash += $"{b:x2}";

            return hash.ToUpper();
        }

        public static string GetHwid() => 
            (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT = FROM Win32_processor").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>() 
                                           select x.GetPropertyValue("ProcessorId")).First().ToString();

        public static string GetUserOs() =>
            (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT = FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                                          select x.GetPropertyValue("Caption")).First().ToString();

        public static string GetHddSerial() =>
             (from x in new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT = FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory").Get().OfType<ManagementObject>()
                                          select x.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber")).First().ToString();

    }
}
```

Главная форма :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using xNet;

namespace kicklag
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
                    return;

                string sign = $"ShockByte·{GetData.GetUserOs()}·{textBox1.Text}·{GetData.GetHwid()}·ShockByte";
                sign = GetData.GetMd5(sign);

                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                RequestParams data = new RequestParams();
                data["login"] = textBox1.Text;
                data["password"] = textBox2.Text;
                data["hwid"] = sign;

                string rsp = req.Post("http://mysoft.local/index.php", data).ToString();
                switch (rsp)
                {
                    case "1":
                        MessageBox.Show("Авторизация успешно");
                        break;
                        

                    case "2":
                        MessageBox.Show("Неверный логие или пароль");
                        break;
                        
                    case "3":
                        MessageBox.Show("HWID привязан");
                        break;
                    case "4":
                        MessageBox.Show("Аккаунт привязан к другому устройству");
                        break;

                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show("Неизвестный ответ");
                        break;
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при запросе!\nEror:{}ex.Message");

            }

        }


    }
}
```

Лог :

```
Вызвано исключение: "System.Management.ManagementException" в System.Management.dll
System.Management.ManagementException: Недопустимый запрос 
   в System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   в System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__95`1.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   в System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   в kicklag.GetData.GetUserOs() в C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\kicklag+php\GetData.cs:строка 35
   в kicklag.Login.buttonLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\kicklag+php\Login.cs:строка 34
```

Comment: `Но не чего не вышло` как вы это поняли?

Comment: Мне выдает ошибку при запросе

Comment: Какую ошибку?..

Comment: Мессадж бокс из catch

Comment: И что же в нем написано?

Comment: Ошибка при запросе!\nEror:{}

Comment: Поправьте строчку `MessageBox.Show($"{ex.GetType().Name}: {ex.Message}", "Ошибка при запросе!");` и потом расскажите, что написано.

Comment: Выдало: Ошибка при запросе! Недопустимый запрос

Comment: Легче не стало. Перед MessageBox добавьте строчку `Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` в окне Visual Studio - Output (Вывод) выведется полный текст ошибки с трассировкой стека. Скопируйте текст и вставьте его в вопрос. Чтобы Debug не подчеркивался, напишите вверху `using System.Diagnostics;`

Comment: Тоже самое(((((

Comment: В какой вопрос надо вставить? Не понятно

Comment: Если вы про тему то исправила тему и добавила лог

Comment: Поправил, убрал лишнее. В следующий раз так и вставляйте ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: Прошу прощения(

Comment: Ну вот собственно и ответ, ошибка возникает в методе `GetUserOs()`. Он не работает. Как исправить - не подскажу.

Comment: Аааа боже мой я ровно поставила заместо *